# Dashboard com essas informações

Tags: php, mysql, css, bootstrap, materialize

estou querendo criar um dashboard simples. exatamente igual a esse!
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

no campo (PEDIDOS) seria a contagem de pedidos do dia atual ou por data.
no campo (RECEITA) seria o valor das vendas no dia atual ou por data.
no campo (TICKET MÉDIO) seria uma média dos valores dos pedidos.

aqui a baixo é os campos do meu mysql. claro de uma determinada Tabela.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o campo (ped_id) é sequencial.
o campo (ped_valor) é o valor da compra.

apesar do meu pouco conhecimento em php. até fiz um, mas não ficou legal!
quem puder me ajudar nesse assunto...
Fico grato!

Comment: Te ajudar com o que? Com o PHP, com o mysql, com o CSS fazendo o layout? Não ficou claro o que vc precisa realmente... O que vc já tem de código? Edite sua resposta com o código etc... E faça o Tour para entender melhor como funciona a plataforma https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Daniel
Voce pode pesquisar nessa tabela, usando o php

Os pedidos:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pedidos WHERE ped_Datahora BETWEEN
'".date("Y-m-)."01 00:00:00' AND '".date(""Y-m-t)."23:59:59'
```

Os valores:

```
SELECT SUM(ped_valor) FROM pedidos WHERE ped_Datahora BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-)."01 00:00:00' AND '".date(""Y-m-t)."23:59:59'
```

O Ticket Médio:

```
SELECT AVG(ped_valor) FROM pedidos WHERE ped_Datahora BETWEEN '".date("Y-m-)."01 00:00:00' AND '".date(""Y-m-t)."23:59:59'.
```

Espero ter ajudado